# How can I validate email addresses flawlessly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help validating proper email addresses. I've managed to solve empty fields, but I also need to solve not proper email address. I mean that, if I input a something that's not an email address, it gives me a message saying "Please enter a proper email address". How can I find the empty value that I can use for this validations?

This:

```js
if (x == "what goes here?")
   {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Please enter a proper email address";
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
    return false;
  }
```

The "what goes here?" is a placeholder for you to replace with the answer.

And, without much more speaking, here's the code for the site:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
p#demo {
  padding: 5px;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
  border: red solid 1px;
  color: red;
  display: none;
  max-width: 140px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
input[type="email"] {
  padding: 4px;
  }
input[type="email"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
</style>
<script>
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["EMAIL"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Email address is required.";
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
    return false;
  }
   if (x == "what goes here?")
   {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Please enter a proper email address";
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="https://gmail.us19.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=f206f10b38a504434c650c6bf&amp;id=5ce815006b" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" >
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <input type="email" name="EMAIL">
  <input type="submit" value="Sign up!">
  
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't do it. Even if you had a perfect email address parser, which is surprisingly complicated, that doesn't tell you anything about whether the email address actually *works*. Here's one: "nobody@does.not.exist.com".  Perfect syntax, does not work.

Comment: Question is too broad, you need to do your research first. A Google search for "javascript email validation" (or "form validation") will give you many tutorials. If you want a simple solution without too much effort, you could check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email as a first step. Browser support is quite good. If you need more flexibility, you'll need a JavaScript-based solution.

Comment: what do you mean @Pointy?

Comment: Any reason why you want to validate email address? Just send an email and see if the user gets it, i.e. confirmation email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was just recently creating a form with email address validation, I used a Regular Expression:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,}|[0-9]{1,})(\]?)$
```

What I am thinking you can do with this, is the following:

```js
function validateEmail() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Please enter a proper email address";
  document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="email" pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0- 9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,}|[0-9]{1,})(\]?)$" placeholder="Email Address" oninvalid="validateEmail()" />
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

But, that will also create a HTML5 default validation bubble to come. So, if you don't want that add this to your JavaScript (**Note**: This will affect your whole form):

```
document.addEventListener('invalid', (function(){
    return function(e) {
      //prevent the browser from showing default error bubble / hint
      e.preventDefault();
      // optionally fire off some custom validation handler
      // myValidation();
    };
})(), true);
```

This will disable the default validation, but will keep your validation. I hope this helps you!

**EDIT**: I know a regular expression (RegEx) is not the BEST way, but this one has never failed me in all my forms.

Comment: Almost *any* regex will exclude actual valid email addresses. Why would you want to tell a customer that the address they *know* to be correct actually isn't?

Comment: @Pointy Well, this one has been tested, and is used in many places. In fact, I got this one off this site, as it was the "client-side" validation that was used to validate the email address to make an account here. I'm pretty sure it should work...

Comment: Modern sites allow a whole lot more characters in email addresses than just old-school ASCII.